# Error: Declarations may only be used within style rules

Tags: sass, mixins

I declared my @mixin, and it didn't give me any problems, out of nowhere it started giving this error:

```
@mixin flexbox ($justify-content: center, $align-items: center, $flex-direction: column, $flex-wrap:wrap) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: $justify-content;
    align-items: $align-items;
    flex-direction: $flex-direction;
    flex-wrap: $flex-wrap;
}
```

```
Compilation Error
Error: Declarations may only be used within style rules.
  ╷
2 │     display: flex;
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

Does anyone have an idea where the error could come from? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you using it? The error tells that it can only be used inside a style rule. For example: `.some-selector { flexbox() }`. You can't use it in the root of an SCSS file.

Answer (score 0):

[SCSS mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin/) work using 2 at-rules. `@mixin`, and `@include`.

To use a mixin like

```scss
@mixin flexbox ($justify-content: center, $align-items: center, $flex-direction: column, $flex-wrap:wrap) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: $justify-content;
    align-items: $align-items;
    flex-direction: $flex-direction;
    flex-wrap: $flex-wrap;
}
```

you call the include at-rule within a CSS declaration block (or style rules) like this.
Which is what the error is referring to.

```scss
// <-- Can't be used here, because it would output invalid CSS.

.my-flex-element {
    @include flexbox;
    // other rules
    background: #333;
}
```

Which outputs

```css
.my-flex-element {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #333;
}
```

Sass has an [awesome playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/) to see output immediately on one screen.
It's great for exploring all of Sass's features.